# TypeError: this is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, this, state

I cannot reach this.state or I cannot `setState` inside the `componentDidMount` function. Why?

```
import React from 'react';

class LoginApi extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formNames: [],
        };
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        let apiKey = '###';
        window.JF.initialize({ apiKey: apiKey });
        window.JF.login(
            function success() {
                window.JF.getForms(function(response) {
                    for (var i in response) {
                        this.setState({ formNames: [...this.state.formNames, response[i]] });
                    }
                });
            },
            function error() {
                window.alert('Could not authorize user');
            }
        );
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="initializeForm">
                <ul>
                    {this.state.formNames.map(forms => (
                        <li key={forms}>{forms}</li>
                    ))}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default LoginApi;
```

When I have tried to this code I am getting `TypeError: this is undefined.`

```
this.setState({formNames: [...this.state.formNames,response[i]]});
```

Comment: You should concat the array before you set state, because setState is asynchronous and will not return the updated array within the for loop. Only the last item will be added to your array.

Comment: never ever post your api key or other credentials.

Answer (score 5):

Because you are referencing `this` within another function. When you create your callback function in `JF.login` and again in `JF.getForms` with the **function** keyword, it creates a [new `this` context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context), hence why `setState` is undefined.

A common way to fix this is by using an [arrow function (`=>`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which will end up using the `this` from its enclosing lexical scope, which in your case is the class.

```
window.JF.login(
    () => {
        window.JF.getForms((response) => {
            for (var i in response) {
                this.setState({ formNames: [...this.state.formNames, response[i]] });
            }
        });
    },
    () => {
        window.alert('Could not authorize user');
    }
);
```

Comment: It is still not working unfortunately. The warning which I have taken in the link below
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n3iaxaeUZdRIFxJ-VbheoL8QUZSaqGG9/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, [StackOverflow isn't for general debugging help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), I'd recommend reading the error you are receiving and going from there. That is, [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) returns _Object Keys_, which you are then concatenating onto your state array, which you are then trying to render, hence why React is throwing this error. Did you mean to use a [`for ... of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement instead?

Answer (score 4):

Because you write the success function without bind / not as an arrow function. Without it, this refers to the calling function. In this case, to the success function. Change it to an arrow function and it will work. () => {...}